# Use variables in module sh

Tags: python

I'm writing a script to display all the ips of a server's NIC, but I have a question.

How do I use variables correctly with the `sh` module in Python?

A example of my code:

```
allinterfaces = os.popen('/sbin/ifconfig -s |awk {\'print $1\'} |grep -v Iface')#.read().strip()

for interface in allinterfaces:
   print interface
   print sh.grep(sh.ifconfig('eth0'), "-oP", "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}")
```

My question is: how do I change 'eth0' for a variable?

Comment: To substitute the variable called `interface`, you just call `sh.ifconfig(interface)` instead of `sh.ifconfig('eth0')`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I did it: `print sh.grep(sh.ifconfig(interface)` the part output is:  RAN: '/sbin/ifconfig eth0\n'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import socket
print([ip for ip in socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] if not ip.startswith("127.")][:1])
```